# Create Linked Table in MS-Access DB on web server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access-2003

getting error when trying to create linked table in access DB on web server - error is on the `ADOX.Catalog` not sure if I need to inherit ADOX or how?

error is:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'ADODB.Catalog' is not defined.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
                        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Dim A As String = "e:\web\Training.mdb"
            Dim B As String = "e:\web\LeaveDB.mdb"
            Dim C As String = "UsersDataTbl"
            Dim D As String = "NewUsers"

            CreateLinkedAccessTable(A,B,C,D)
            End Sub             


            Sub CreateLinkedAccessTable(strDBLinkFrom As String, strDBLinkTo As String, strLinkTbl As String, strLinkTblAs As String)

                Dim catDB As ADOX.Catalog
                Dim tblLink As ADOX.Table

                Set catDB = New ADOX.Catalog
                    ' Open a Catalog on the database in which to create the link.
                catDB.ActiveConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & strDBLinkFrom

                Set tblLink = New ADOX.Table
                With tblLink
                    ' Name the new Table and set its ParentCatalog property to the
                    ' open Catalog to allow access to the Properties collection.
                .Name = strLinkTblAs
                Set .ParentCatalog = catDB

                    ' Set the properties to create the link.
                .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True
                .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Datasource") = strDBLinkTo
                .Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = strLinkTbl
                End With

                    ' Append the table to the Tables collection.
                catDB.Tables.Append tblLink

                Set catDB = Nothing
            End Sub
```

Comment: Here is a link to sample code I'm using: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164914(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: sounds like you are missing a reference or imports.  might be a nugget buried here: http://allenbrowne.com/func-adox.html  (up at the top it talks about the ref)  Look like it is a COM object on my system

Comment: Yea, I looked at that, can't find the dll to include since I'm doing this on a 3rd party server

Comment: This might be a new problem...mine is MSADOX.TLB (ext 2.8) there is also ext 6.0 as MSADOX.DLL but that one "already exists" though I cant see it. 2.8 shows a Catalog object in the object browser, FWIW  They are in Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System, you arent going to have a 32bit vs 64bit problem are you?  Access 2003 I should think not... Ext 6.0 worked thru Project Props -> Refs, let me make an ADOX cat object.

Comment: I'm working from a Mac, don't have access to MS files and my site is hosted on 2007 IIS7 remote hosting, so I need to fine interop.ADOX.dll file and load to BIN on server, don't feel safe just grabing any ell out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use ADOX you need to open your ASP.NET project and add the following COM reference:

`Microsoft ADO Ext. 2.8 for DDL and Security`

Comment: Can I link to another access DB table without ADOX.dll? example: To get the Access datatable schema, use OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable method via ADO.NET. can the linked table data be updated with OLEDB not ADOX?

Comment: @BarclayVision You may not need to. I will post an answer to your other question.